# Is Sanguine Bond + Exquisite Blood a potential game ender?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If both [Sanguine Bond](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sanguine%20Bond) and [Exquisite Blood](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Exquisite%20Blood) are in play and target player loses any life, is the game over?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either your opponent will have to lose life or you will have to gain life to start the process. Then, yes, unless someone does something to stop it, you'll enter a loop which will win you the game.

As hinted above, there are numerous effects that can change the outcome. If an opponent controls [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlatinum%20Angel%5d), if they cast [Angel's Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%27s%5d%2b%5bGrace%5d), or if you control [Abyssal Persecutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAbyssal%20Persecutor%5d), the game will enter into a loop of mandatory actions which will end the game in a draw. If an opponent has hexproof or shroud for some reason (e.g. [Witchbane Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWitchbane%20Orb%5d), [True Believer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrue%20Believer%5d)), Sanguine Bond won't be able to target him or her and the loop will terminate. [Voidslime](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoidslime%5d) can end the loop (but doesn't prevent from being restarted later).

Comment: Note: If an opponent controls Platinum Angel or casts Angel's Grace, or you control Abyssal Persecutor, this will enter into a loop of mandatory actions which will end the game in a draw. If an opponent has hexproof or shroud for some reason (Witchbane Orb, True Believer, etc.), Sanguine Bond won't be able to target him or her and the loop will terminate.

Comment: @Brian S, Thanks for the examples. I have incorporated them into the answer. Credit in the edit description.

Answer (score -7):

Actually, you will not win.  According to the comprehensive rules on infinite loops, if a loop contains only mandatory effects, the game ends in a draw.  Since the cards don't say may, they are mandatory.  Sorry no game winning combo here.

Comment: They're just regular triggered abilities, so they use the stack. That means you'll check for state-based effects between each trigger. Losing the game due to running out of life is one such state-based effect. At that point, the game just ends; it doesn't matter if there's another trigger still on the stack now.

Comment: The general idea of the rules on infinite loops is that it's a draw if there's really no way at all for them to stop. The end of the game is a perfectly good way for a loop to end, as is a player deciding to do something that breaks the loop. It's when a mandatory loop does something that *doesn't* end the game that it's a problem.

Comment: In short, players regularly get priority, so this loop doesn't contain only mandatory effects.

Comment: the loop DOES contain only mandatory actions. players still getting priority is not related. A more accurate explanation of the reason this is wrong, is if a player will win as a result of the loop being executed N times, it is therefore a non-infinite loop. the rule informing the answer above only applies if the loop cannot terminate regardless of how many times it is executed. if players get priority, they can (but do not have to) perform actions to interrupt the loop to stop the draw. But the game should still end in a draw if they regularly get priority but are unable to stop the loop.

Comment: @Patters is correct. This _is_ an infinite loop of mandatory actions... but barring something like Platinum Angel in play, it will end the game rather than resulting in a draw.

Answer (score -7):

the combo one goes till the opponent is at 0 life it is not infinite. The life has to come from somewhere if no opponent has life/ they are at 0 life the the combo ends. And the hex proof/ platinum angel thing do stop the combo but not in a draw. The opponent will be at zero, just not dead.

Comment: -1; The only thing that ends the combo is one of the two enchantments leaving the battlefield, one of the triggers being removed from the stack (temporarily interrupting the combo), or the controlling player running out of targets (either by eliminating all opposing players, or all remaining opposing players having shroud/hexproof). Platinum Angel, Phyrexian Unlife, etc. results in a draw.

Comment: Players can lose life to go below zero. What they can't do is *spend* life to go below zero (so you can't, say, use Yawgmoth's Bargain to draw your entire deck even if you have Platinum Angel in play)